# XSLT default template won't let one element disappear

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, latexml

I am confused here why the `resource` tag is still there within `<body>`, because I think the default template for `ltx:resource` should let it appear.

I have the XML file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?latexml RelaxNGSchema="LaTeXML"?>
<document xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML" xmlns:stex="http://kwarc.info/ns/sTeX" xml:id="Document">
<resource src="LaTeXML.css" type="text/css"/>
<resource src="ltx-article.css" type="text/css"/>
<para class="theory" xml:id="p1" fragid="p1">
  <block class="definition" xml:id="foo" fragid="foo">
   <p xml:id="foo.p1" about="#foo.p1" stex:srcref="/Users/yuancalvin/lmh/localmh/ext/sTeX/htmltest/test.tex#textrange(from=9;0,to=11;16)" fragid="foo.p1"> 
  testing 
   </p>
  </block>
</para>
</document>
```

The part of XSL responsible for the construction as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version     = "1.0"
    xmlns:xsl   = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ltx   = "http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML"
    xmlns:string= "http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:f     = "http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes = "ltx f"
    extension-element-prefixes="string f">

 <xsl:template match="/" mode="head-resources">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ltx:resource[@type='text/css']
                                 | //ltx:resource[@type='text/javascript']" mode="inhead"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- By default, these disappear -->
  <xsl:template match="ltx:resource"/>

  <xsl:template match="ltx:resource[@type='text/css' and @src]" mode="inhead">
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:element name="link" namespace="{$html_ns}">
      <xsl:attribute name="rel">stylesheet</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="f:url(@src)"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:if test="@media">
        <xsl:attribute name="media"><xsl:value-of select="@media"/></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/" mode="body-main-begin"/>
  <xsl:template match="/" mode="body-main-end"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" mode="body-content">
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:element name="div" namespace="{$html_ns}">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">ltx_page_content</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="body-content-begin"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="body-content-end"/>
      <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" mode="body-content-begin"/>
  <xsl:template match="/" mode="body-content-end"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet is nevertheless incomplete as the actual one is rather long but should be enough for error inspection.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="LaTeXML.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ltx-article.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ltx_page_main">
<div class="ltx_page_content">
  <resource xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML" src="LaTeXML.css" type="text/css"/>
  <resource xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML" src="ltx-article.css" type="text/css"/>
  <para xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML" class="theory" xml:id="p1">

    <block class="definition" xml:id="foo">
      <p xmlns:stex="http://kwarc.info/ns/sTeX" xml:id="foo.p1" about="#foo.p1" stex:srcref="/Users/yuancalvin/lmh/localmh/ext/sTeX/htmltest/test.tex#textrange(from=9;0,to=11;16)">
testing </p>
    </block>
  </para>


</div>
<div class="ltx_page_footer">
<div class="ltx_page_logo">Generated  by <a href="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/">LaTeXML <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="[LOGO]"/></a></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really know why the resource tags still exist in the body. Any help will be highly appreciated : )

Comment: "*The stylesheet is nevertheless incomplete as the actual one is rather long but should be enough for error inspection.*" No, it is not - because it does not produce the claimed result (actually, it only produces an error, due to undeclared variable). Please review:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Angerhang, on StackOverflow, to mark a question solved, _do not edit its title with "[solved]"_, just click the checkmark (which you did, thanks). I'll revert your title change.

Comment: Thanks for the correction : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show the part where you are copying the nodes, so as currently written, if the match fails, the output would be the text value of that node.

Your code has this:

> ```
> <!-- By default, these disappear -->
> <xsl:template match="ltx:resource"/>
> ```

The part that you did show, shows an `xsl:apply-templates` in mode `inhead`, but the "delete template" does not exist in that mode. Hence it will never be matched.

You will need to add the delete template in every mode where you want it applied to. If you were using XSLT 2.0 (currently it is tagged XSLT 1.0), you can use the `<xsl:template match="X" mode="#all" />` syntax, but unfortunately, in XSLT 1.0 you are stuck with specifying this for each mode separately.

The specification [says it so](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule):

> There is also a built-in template rule for each mode, which allows recursive processing to continue in the same mode in the absence of a successful pattern match by an explicit template rule in the stylesheet. This template rule applies to both element nodes and the root node. The following shows the equivalent of the built-in template rule for mode m.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/" mode="m">
>   <xsl:apply-templates mode="m"/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```